# Using sub-query to generate case statements

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

What i am trying to accomplish is comparing two rows to each other pointing out the differences from row to row.  Each row has quite a few columns and I was trying to make it easily visible for which ones had changed.  Code below is my thoughts, but I know this won't work, but is a start.

```
SELECT 
        (SELECT  concat('Case WHEN T1.', column_name, ' <> T2.', column_name, ' THEN ''', column_name, ' Changed Values('' + CONVERT(varchar(100), T1.', column_name, ') + '', '' + CONVERT(varchar(100), T2.', column_name, ') + '')'' ELSE '''' END AS ', column_name)
        FROM    information_schema.columns
        WHERE   table_name = 'Table')
    FROM
    (
        SELECT * FROM Table
        WHERE ID = '13'
    ) AS T1 
    JOIN
    (
        SELECT * FROM Table
        WHERE ID = '2006'
    ) AS T2 
        ON T1.CreateTimeStamp = T2.CreateTimeStamp
```

I got the idea because below this works fine, but I would like this to be potentially reusable code for other table without having to type out tens or hundreds of columns each time.

```
 SELECT 
    Case WHEN T1.R1<> T2.R1 THEN 'Changed Values(' + CONVERT(varchar(100),T1.R1)    + ', ' + CONVERT(varchar(100),T2.R1) + ')' ELSE '' END AS R1,
    Case WHEN T1.R2<> T2.R2 THEN 'Changed Values(' + CONVERT(varchar(100),T1.R2)    + ', ' + CONVERT(varchar(100),T2.R2) + ')' ELSE '' END AS R2
FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM Table
    WHERE ID = '13'
) AS T1 
JOIN
(
    SELECT * FROM Table
    WHERE ID = '2006'
) AS T2 
    ON T1.CreateTimeStamp = T2.CreateTimeStamp
```

For the this example please assume CreateTimeStamp always equals each other between the two rows.

Comment: you should be able to use the columns meta data table in the information schema to make dynamic sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to create the whole query as dynamic SQL. Note that I'm using `QUOTENAME()` to prevent SQL Injection from weirdly named columns. I'm also trying to keep a format for the code, so I won't get headaches when debugging.

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @SQL = N' SELECT ' + NCHAR(10)
            --Concatenate all columns except ID and CreateTimeStamp
            + STUFF(( SELECT REPLACE( CHAR(9) + ',CASE WHEN T1.<<ColumnName>> <> T2.<<ColumnName>> ' + CHAR(10) 
                        +  CHAR(9) + CHAR(9) + 'THEN ''Changed Values('' + CONVERT(varchar(100),T1.<<ColumnName>>)    + '', '' + CONVERT(varchar(100),T2.<<ColumnName>>) + '')'' ' + CHAR(10) 
                        +  CHAR(9) + CHAR(9) + 'ELSE '''' END AS <<ColumnName>>', '<<ColumnName>>', QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME)) + NCHAR(10)
                    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                    WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Table'
                    AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN( 'ID', 'CreateTimeStamp')
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('./text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 2, 1, '') + NCHAR(10)
            --Add rest of the query
            + 'FROM Table AS T1 ' + NCHAR(10)
            + 'JOIN Table AS T2 ON T1.CreateTimeStamp = T2.CreateTimeStamp ' + NCHAR(10)
            + 'WHERE ID = @ID1 ' + NCHAR(10)
            + 'AND ID = @ID2;'
--PRINT for debugging purposes
PRINT @SQL;
--Execute the dynamic built code
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL, 
                    N'@ID1 int, @ID2 int', 
                    @ID1 = 13, 
                    @ID2 = 2006;
```

The concatenation method is explained on [this article](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/comma+separated+list/71700/).

Comment: Thanks, this worked like a charm.  Only thing that needed tweaked was `WHERE ID = @ID1...`  It just needed the Alias's before them. You've taught me quite a bit through this  for dynamic SQL.